# Pulling value from cells in Excel based on top 5 value in a different column

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

Let's say column A has ten names in it, and column B ten values. I want the names of the people with the five highest column B values, in order, to populate on a different sheet. How would I do this? What if I wanted the lowest values?

Comment: [Please show a) sample data b) expected results c) what you have tried (working or not).](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Address the issue of ties in the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use `vlookup` to achieve the same but since your `lookup value` comes before the column you are looking up against then you need to use `choose` function to resolve this:
always using the same example table 
[image]

put this formula in **C2** to pull the top 5:

```
=VLOOKUP(LARGE($B$2:$B$99,ROW(1:1)),CHOOSE({2\1},$A$2:$A$99,$B$2:$B$99),2,0)
```

and put this in **D2** to pull the low 5:

```
=VLOOKUP(SMALL($B$2:$B$99,ROW(1:1)),CHOOSE({2\1},$A$2:$A$99,$B$2:$B$99),2,0)
```

hope this works as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `index` `match`function to achieve this:

[image]

Given the above example table:

Formula to pull top 5, put this in **C2**:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$99,MATCH(1,INDEX(($B$2:$B$99=LARGE($B$2:$B$99,ROWS(C$1:C1)))*(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,$A$2:$A$99)=0),),0))
```

Formula to pull low 5, put this in **D2**:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$99,MATCH(1,INDEX(($B$2:$B$99=SMALL($B$2:$B$99,ROWS(D$1:D1)))*(COUNTIF(D$1:D1,$A$2:$A$99)=0),),0))
```

For both, drag and fill down for 5 rows (because you want top/low 5). you can drag/fill down as many as you want.
you can adapt it to fit the lenght of your column by changing the $A$99 and $B$99 to any number of rows you have.
tell me if it works for you.